# Transform fix value into a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

I would like to transform a fix value cell like this one `5` into a formula cell that contains the same value as before, i.e. `=5`. Is there any simple way to do it?. I can use vba to get the value and overwrite the cell but I would like to know whether there is a simpler way.

Comment: Any of the 2 people that down vote the question can provide a solution? because I have a huge list of constant values that I would like to treat as formulas and not just as fix values. In the internet there are lots of posts to do the opposite, i.e. convert formulas to fix values, but not the other way round.

Comment: do you want to place "=" before every cells content?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. As posted above I could use a vba code to do it, but I would like to know if there is a simple way to do it. By placing the "=" in front of the number I can use the cell as it contained a formula, so, for example, I could use "copy>paste special>multiply" and modify the formula, avoiding modifying the original number.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this vba code! Change the range to your actual destination range

```
Sub toFormula()
Dim Rg As Range

Set Rg = Range("A1:B4") 'just for example you can change to any range
For Each cell In Rg
    If Mid(cell.FormulaR1C1, 1, 1) <> "=" Then
     cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & cell.FormulaR1C1
    End If
Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the code Tristanto, but I would like to know whether there is a way where vba is not used, which was pointed out on the first post. 
If there is no way to make it without vba I will definitely use the code you posted above.

Comment: I'm sorry for my misunderstanding. :(